# Code runs fine in Eclipse but throws NumberFormatException in CodeChef

Tags: java, numberformatexception

The code is working perfectly fine on Eclipse IDE but on Codechef, compiler is showing this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null    
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:542)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
at Codechef.main(Main.java:19)
```

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
class Codechef {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        int x = 0, j = 0;
        String s;
        int counta = 0, countb = 0;
        int countf[] = new int[5];
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int i = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        while (j < i) {
            s = br.readLine();
            for (int k = 0; k < s.length(); k++) {
                if (s.charAt(k) == 'a') {
                    counta++;
                }
                else {
                    countb++;
                }
            }
            if (counta < countb) {
                countf[j] = counta;
            }
            else {
                countf[j] = countb;
            }
            j++;
            counta = countb = 0;
        }

        for (int g = 0; g < i; g++) {
            System.out.println(countf[g]);
        }
    }
}
```

I even tried using scanner class but in that it was showing `NoSuchElementException`.

Comment: Well it sounds like CodeChef isn't providing any input on `System.in`. Are you sure you should expect it to for this problem?

Comment: i dont know i have tried several times but i saw solutions of other coders too they have used System.in and they have succsessful submissions

Comment: i think codechef compiler is down because i ran the code which have been successfully submitted and it is showing the same error

Comment: You dint post the problem you are trying to solve by the code. I suggest you to read the question again may be its written to validate the input and return the output accoding to it

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
int i = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
```

you are trying to parse to integer the input but you are not validating if the input **IS ACTUALLY SOMETHING THAT CAN BE PARSED TO INTEGER**

you need to validate the input and only go forward when the input correct is:

## Example

```
int i = -1;
    while (i == -1) {
        try {
        i = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Wrong input");
        }
    }
```

Comment: so what should i do?

Comment: ok its working i selected the custom input thanks but still on codechef it is still not getting accepted it is showing runtime error(NZEC) although my code is running on codechef compiler

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `throws`, use `try` and `catch`. It works fine with me

Answer (score 0):

You should validate your input before parsing it for Integer or any other Object...

```
String str = br.readLine();
    if(null!=str)
        val = Integer.parseInt(str);
```